# Does the binomial theorem hold by default for the Cartesian Product of intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was wondering if the binomial theorem holds for Cartesian products of intervals?
For example, does this inequality hold:

$$[(a,b) + (c,d)] ^2=(a,b) \times (a,b)+2\cdot(a,b) \times (c,d)+(c,d) \times (c,d)\ \text{?}$$

I somehow feel that this is a dumb question but still hope that I get a clarifying answer. Thank you in advance...

Comment: How is $(a,b) \times (c,d)$ defined?

Comment: How is $2\times(a,b)\times (c,d)$ defined? And wouldn't we expect a $+$ on the left side? -- That being said, we have $(X+Y)\times (X+Y)=X\times X+2\cdot(X\times Y)+Y\times Y$ whenever $+$ and $\times $ are binary operations such that$+$ is associative and  $\times$ is abelian and distributes over $+$, and if we define $n\cdot X$ as $\underbrace{X+\ldots +X}_{n}$.

Comment: The left-hand side is (was, before the edit) four-dimensional and the right-hand side is a linear combination of rectangles. At best it appears you're expecting the Cartesian product to behave like addition. Maybe consider using a disjoint union instead: A product of a disjoint union of intervals is the disjoint union of rectangles, where the coefficients signify counting the number of "copies"?

Comment: First of all, thank both of you,  Hagen von Eitzen and Andrew D. Hwang  for your help, As already noted, I made some corrections. I studied physics before and am trying to get better in math, so please be patient if I make elementary mistakes. @Hagen von Eitzen if "+" means the usual addition and "x" the Cartesian Product, does this relation hold? I mean aren't they assumed to satisfy this conditions you mentioned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ are sets (such as intervals of real numbers), define $I_{1} + I_{2}$ to be their [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union) and $I_{1} \times I_{2}$ to be their [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Since the Cartesian product distributes over disjoint unions,
$$
(I_{1} + I_{2}) \times (I_{1} + I_{2})
  = (I_{1} \times I_{1}) + (I_{1} \times I_{2}) + (I_{2} \times I_{1}) + (I_{2} \times I_{2}).
$$
An analogous identity holds for an $n$-fold Cartesian product.

Moreover, $I_{2} \times I_{1}$ is naturally identified with $I_{1} \times I_{2}$, and the "cross term"
$$
2(I_{1} \times I_{2})
$$
may be interpreted as "two copies of $I_{1} \times I_{2}$". In this sense (up to re-ordering factors in an $n$-fold Cartesian product) an $n$-fold product of a disjoint union satisfies a formal binomial theorem
$$
(I_{1} + I_{2})^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} I_{1}^{n-k} \times I_{2}^{k}.
$$
This can be visualized for $n = 2$ or $n = 3$ (below) using the types of diagram often used to prove the product rule for derivatives. (The colors signify "factors", and the heavy lines show one of the "summands".)

[image: A Cartesian product of a union of intervals]